# UNIX sed command not removing spaces in cat output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a file as below.

```
Hi this is first line
    this is second line
    this is third line
```

Expected is:

```
Hi this is first line
this is second line
this is third line
```

What i used is

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/ //g'
```

returns,

```
Hi this is first line
    this is second line
    this is third line
```

Comment: You should probably `cat -A` or `od -t x1 -c` that file to see if those are really ASCII spaces.

Answer (score 3):

For a portable sed command use this:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' file
```

`[[:blank:]]` matches space or tab.

**EDIT:** To remove all spaces using awk:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS= file
```

OR sed:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*//g' file
```

Comment: To remove all spaces using sed use `sed 's/[[:blank:]]*//g' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
 cat file.txt | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

OR

```
 sed 's/^[ \t]*//' file.txt
```

OR if you want to modify file.txt and remove the white spaces in the beginning of the line :

```
sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//' file.txt
```

Comment: how to remove spaces inbetween words as well ?

Answer (score 1):

`sed` in your example will replace all the spaces

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//' file.txt
```

Comment: it may have tab or space in the starting . will it solve both ?

Comment: how to remove spaces inbetween words as well ?

Comment: @logan add a g for global replace to the substitute: sed 's/^[ \t]*//g' file.txt

Answer (score 1):

try this line

```
sed -r 's/^\s*//' file
```

to remove all spaces(tabs): `sed -r 's/\s//g' file`

```
kent$ echo "Hi this is first line
    this is second line
    this is third line"|sed -r 's/\s//g' 
Hithisisfirstline
thisissecondline
thisisthirdline
```

Comment: how to remove spaces inbetween words as well ?

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to remove all blanks from your input is probably not using `sed` at all, but

```
tr -d '[:blank:]' < file.txt
```

That's different from what you have originally asked for, though (removing initial whitespace only).

Comment: but it also remove blank after the first non blank character and not sur it is lot more efficient than sed

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Well the OP asked for removal of all blanks in the comments later, and `tr` *is* much more efficient than `sed`, as you can see when you benchmark it with, for example `perl -le 'print "a "x10000000' | time $TR_OR_SED_COMMAND >/dev/null`.

Comment: ok, didn't see sub comment in Amit reply. tr is than faster :-)